# LARAVEL use single form for both Edit and Insert actions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

in my application i want to simplify forms and change `Form::model` to use both of Update and Insert, for have this ability i'm create this `route:controller` to show View and modrate it:

```
Route::controller(
    'customers' , 'customersController',
    array(
        'getIndex'  =>'customers.index',
        'postUpdate'=>'customers.update'
    )
);
```

`customersController` controller class:

```
<?php
class customersController extends \BaseController
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        if ( Auth::check() ){
            $customers = new Customers;
            return View::make('layouts.customers')->with('customers', $customers);
        }
        return Redirect::route('dashboard');
    }
    public function postUpdate($id)
    {
        print_r( $id);
        die;
    }
}

?>
```

in `getIndex` i can return to view customers.blade.php corretcly and i can be create new variable as an `new Customers`, in view i'm create below form from created new instance from Customers:

```
{{ Form::model($customers,array('route' => array('customers.update', $customers->id))) }}
...
{{ Form::submit('UPDATE', array('class'=>'btn btn-default btn-default-small') ) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

now i want to send form values to controler, but after send i get this error:

**ERROR:**

```
 Missing argument 1 for customersController::postUpdate()
```

Comment: Please, do not abuse of tags: Is this Laravel 4 or Laravel 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form in view must be like with this code :

```
{{ Form::model($customers,array('route' => array('customers.update', $customers->id))) }}
```

and your `Form::text` must be like with:

```
{{ Form::text('name', $customers->name, array('class'=>'form-control rtl' ) ) }}
```

Route:

```
Route::controller(
    'customers', 'customersController',
    array(
        'getIndex' => 'customers.index',
        'postUpdate' => 'customers.update'
    )
);
```

now in controller you can try this code to detect form is update or insert

```
public function postUpdate()
{
    if (Input::get('id')) {
        $customer = Customers::find(Input::get('id'));
    } else {
        $customer = new Customers;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```